# ffmpeg - subtitle and watermark in video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to include subtitle and watermark in the same video.
That's what i tried:

```
for %%a in ("original\720p\*.*") do  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -vf ass=subtitle.ass -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart "newfiles\720p\%%~na.mp4"
```

i got this error:

> -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix `-vf`/`-af`/`-filter` and `-filter_complex`. Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas:

```
for %%a in ("original\720p\*.*") do  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10,ass=subtitle.ass" -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -movflags faststart "newfiles\720p\%%~na.mp4"
```

See [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.

I removed `-strict -2`: it has not been needed for the AAC encoder since 2015.